# Using datetime expression in alias

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, date

I have an application with logging, and I usually watch it with

```
tail -f /var/myapp/logs/2021-04-20/main-log-2021-04-20.log
```

How can I create an alias for this command and execute it with current date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `date` command to output the current date in your desired format:

```
$ date +%F
2021-03-21
```

(see `man date` for a list of formats available)

So you could use `date` in command substitution to construct your command like this:

```
tail -f /var/myapp/logs/$(date +%F)/main-$(date +%F).log
```

Alias expansion is performed before any other shell expansion, so the result of alias expansion will be subject to parameter expansion, meaning you can alias the above and get the expected command:

```
alias foo='tail -f /var/myapp/logs/$(date +%F)/main-$(date +%F).log'
```

After testing this you can add the `alias` line (of course you can call your alias something other than `foo`...) to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` file to be able to use it any time.